# union of two files with array

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, boolean

I am beginner of Java.

I am trying to read two files and then get the union of them. I should use an array with size 100. (only one array allowed)

First, I read all records from `file1`, and write them to the output, `file3`. For that purpose, I read 100 records at a time, and write them to `file3` using iteration.

After that, like `file1`, this time I read second file as 100 records at a time, and write them to the array, `memory[]`. Then I find the common records, if the record which I read from `file2` is not in `file1`, I write it to the output file. I do this until `reader2.readLine()` gets `null` and I re-open `file1` in each iteration.

This is what I have done so far, almost done, but it gives `NullPointerException`. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: ok, now it doesn't give any exception, but it doesn't find the different records and can't write them. I guess the last for loop and booleans don't work , why? please help...

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileUnion
{
private static long startTime, endTime;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    System.out.println("PROCESSING...");
    reset();
    startTimer();

    String[] memory = new String[100];
    int memorySize = memory.length;

    File file1 = new File("stdlist1.txt");
    BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));

    File file3 = new File("union.txt");
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file3));

    int numberOfLinesFile1 = 0;
    String line1 = null;
    String line11 = null;


    while((line1 = reader1.readLine()) != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < memorySize; )
        {
            memory[i] = line1;
            i++;

            if(i < memorySize)
            {
                line1 = reader1.readLine();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < memorySize; i++)
        {
            writer.write(memory[i]);
            writer.newLine();
            numberOfLinesFile1++;
        }
    }

    reader1.close();

    File file2 = new File("stdlist2.txt");
    BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2));

    String line2 = null;
    while((line2 = reader2.readLine()) != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < memorySize; )
        {
            memory[i] = line2;
            i++;

            if(i < memorySize)
            {
                line2 = reader2.readLine();
            }
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < memorySize; k++ )
        {
            boolean found = false;
            File f1 = new File("stdlist1.txt");
            BufferedReader buff1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f1));

            for (int m = 0; m < numberOfLinesFile1; m++)
            {
                line11 = buff1.readLine();

                if (line11.equals(memory[k]) && found == false);
                {
                    found = true;
                }

            }
            buff1.close();

            if (found == false)
            {
                writer.write(memory[k]);
                writer.newLine();
            }


        }       
    }

    reader2.close();
    writer.close();

    endTimer();
    long time = duration();
    System.out.println("PROCESS COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY");
    System.out.println("Duration: " + time + " ms");

}

public static void startTimer()
{
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
public static void endTimer()
{
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
public static long duration()
{
    return endTime - startTime;
}
public static void reset()
{
    startTime = 0;
    endTime = 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to check that you've not yet reached the end of the file. In all loops where you have a `lineX = readerX.readLine()`, immediately check whether `lineX == null` and break out of the loop if it is.

Edit my own answer because code doesn't show well in comments.

```
while(!line11.equals(memory[k]))
    {
        line11 = buff1.readLine();
    }
```

It's `line11` that is (sometimes) null here. If `memory[k]` is not in file1, what happens?

Comment: if memory[k] is not in file1, it just keeps reading until they be the same, or not same. if loop checks all records in file1 and not find, then write it to output. right? isn't my approach ok? or is it just code problem? help please.

Comment: If it isn't in f1, the condition of the while loop will never be false, so it keeps on reading until... ?

Answer (score 2):

memory[k] is null. Why is this null? Because in this code:

```
while((line2 = reader2.readLine()) != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                memory[i] = line1;
                i++;

                if(i < 100)
                {
                    line2 = reader2.readLine();
                }
            }
```

you say `memory[i] = line1;`

line1 however is always null because you used it before in a loop which ended when line1 is null.

I believe you intended to write `**memory[i] = line2;**` in the above code :)

Comment: yes. you're right. I intended that. I changed it but still gives nullpointerexception at the same line. :(